# Weird issues on tableview cell and segue

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, segue, nsindexpath

There are couples of wired issue on my `UITableView`

1. To change cell background color for those `indexPath.row = 0`. But some cells are changed also. It looks randomly.
2. Two methods to create `UITableViewCell`, but pretty weird is......, too complicated, please see `SMFirstViewController.m` on
   [github](https://github.com/i0sdev/Temp/blob/segue/Temp/SMFirstViewController.m).
3. `prepareForSegue:sender:` not works as expected. Weirdly, `indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender]` sometimes `indexPath` is `null` in terms of CELL METHOD 1 or 2

These issues look too complicated, so I upload my code onto github. https://github.com/i0sdev/Temp/tree/segue, `SMFirstViewController.m` is the file where issues happen.

Pretty appreciated if you could help to fix! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're not accounting for the cell reuse in method 1 (you shouldn't even use method 2). Once your if statement is executed you will make your cell brown, and when that cell gets reused, it will still be brown no matter what indexPath.row it's in. Whenever you set some property of the cell based on the indexPath like you're doing, you need to have an else clause, not just an if.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    
    static NSString *identifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    
    if (indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor brownColor];
        cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    }else{
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    }
    NSArray * array = [[list objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [array valueForKey:@"Number"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"row: %d", indexPath.row];
    
    return cell;
}
```

As long as you stick with method 1, then the prepareForSegue should work properly.

Comment: why method 2 shouldn't be used? Learning from tutorials that's related to prototype cell, they do cell like method 2 since it looks more simple code.

Comment: @iOS.dev, you shouldn't use that method, because it doesn't reuse the cells, which is inefficient.

Comment: as your codes, the app works! Thanks for your clarify about method. how about segue 2. anything wrong?

Comment: @iOS.dev, no, I would probably use that one not segue 1. There's no reason to test for either the class of the sender or destination view controller -- you set them both up in IB, so you should know what they are.

Comment: Got it. What about `initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1` in method 1. Whatever changing style code manually, nothing happen on simulator display. Why?

Comment: @iOS.dev  because, as you noted, your log in the if (cell == nil) never gets called. The cell is never nil when you make it in a storyboard. You should set the type of cell to "Right Detail" in IB, not custom as you have it now.

Comment: which means `if (cell == nil)` should be removed, just leave `cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"ListCell"];` Am I right?

Comment: @iOS.dev, No, you should have UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier], and the whole if clause should be removed, not just if (cell == nil).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37807/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-ios-dev)

Comment: I tried both way. One is like above my said, `if (cell == nil)` deleted, but `cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"ListCell"];` remained. This works when I change any of CellStyle, regardless what CellStyle is set in storyboard. The second way is like yours, the whole If clause deleted, using `    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];`.

Comment: These two do work. But the difference I figured out is, the first has flexibilities to change cell style manually by codes even if it's already set in storyboard. While the second, cell style completely relies on what set in storyboard. Is my understanding right?